# syntax error in rake breaks on production not locally, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a rake task with incorrect syntax. Obviously i'm the most horrible developer in the world. When i start my rails server locally, nothing breaks. While deploying and running `assets:precompile`, it aborts because the syntax error in a completely separate file but does not have an exit code.

**Question:** *How can I have my `development` Environment raise error like the `production` env does without being ran in `production`?  Would like to see it happen earlier/locally or before the precompile?*

```
output /home/releases/1482452394/lib/tasks/listings.rake:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `block in load_tasks'
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `each'
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `load_tasks'
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
output /home/releases/1482452394/Rakefile:13:in `<top (required)>'
output (See full trace by running task with --trace)
output rake aborted!
output SyntaxError: /home/releases/1482452394/lib/tasks/listings.rake:4: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
output ...id).each_with_index |author_id, index|
output ... ^
output /home/releases/1482452394/lib/tasks/listings.rake:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
output /home/releases/1482452394/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `block in load_tasks'
```

Comment: Log show the error. `lib/tasks/listings.rake` syntax error. Could u show that file? Or at least the code around line 4

Comment: @DuyetNguyen i already know the file has a syntax error and fixed it. My question is about prod vs local syntax errors. How can have my local environment catch the syntax error instead of my production environment?

Comment: you want to run your app on env producion at local?

Comment: `How to have my local environment catch the syntax error instead of my production environment?`

Comment: Did u try to run `rails s -e production` ?

Comment: I do not want to run the server in production. I want to know the lib that is invoked to catch the syntax error and have it run in dev so that my dev env raises errors without needing to be ran in production.

Comment: You should run rake task on local to check if it works first. You can also check syntax of file to make sure it doesn't have error with: `ruby -c lib/tasks/listings.rake`

Comment: you can do rake assets:precompile in development and check whether the error is coming or not